# Ada code instrumentation as GNAT compilation part?

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm looking for a best way to integrate GNAT compiler with our custom code analysis/modification tools. We are using custom tools to perform different code metrics (like execution time, test coverage and etc) and even do some code obfuscation. So for example for measuring code execution time I need to insert 2 procedure calls into each function/procedure (the first one where the function starts, and the other one for each function exit). The code for these 2 procedures are implemented in a separate translation unit. What is the best way to do these code instrumentations (insert/modify code) with GNAT compiler in terms of simplicity and performance?  I can think of these several ways:

1. Does GNAT compiler support code generation plugins of any kind? Seem's that it doesn't, but maybe I missed something while googling about it. Maybe there is a way to do it using some metaprogramming tricks (like in some modern programming languages like Nimrod and D), but I couldn't find if Ada even supports metaprogramming at all.
2. Looks like the ASIS library can help me out, but it is made for creating separate tools. Is it possible to integrate ASIS-based tool with GNAT? So for example to write a tool that would be loaded by GNAT during compilation, and would modify nodes in the AST before it (the AST) is about to be transformed into GIMPLE. Using the ASIS-based tool separately (for example by preprocessing each source file before passing it to compiler) may reduce compilation time, as source code will need to be parsed twice (by the tool and by the compiler) and be saved/loaded to/from some temporary location on disk.
3. Is it possible to get GIMPLE from GNAT compiler, modify and pass it to GCC? I couldn't find if there is a working GIMPLE front-end inside GCC, but it seems that GIMPLE is used internally only. I can dump it with GCC compiler, but I can't recompile modified GIMPLE afterwards (seems that there is no GIMPLE front-end for GCC).

Comment: I take it you don’t want a repeat of my [suggestions on comp.lang.ada](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!searchin/comp.lang.ada/gimple/comp.lang.ada/-vbpvrtnNpI/uwVvou3RWkUJ), then! Best of luck ..

Comment: @SimonWright thank you, but I'd like not to use ASIS-based tool as a separate tool, as sources needs to be parsed and processed twice (by the tool and compiler as well). As for using DragonEgg - it isn't well supported (it mostly support C/C++, Ada is said to work in some test-code) and it is hard to build it for windows (I need to build GCC with plugin support, build LLVM, build DragonEgg plugins for GCC). LLVM IR is good representation for custom code tranformation, but I'd like to use reliable tools, and sadly there is no official and well supported Ada front-end for LLVM.

Comment: LLVM has a major blind spot re: nested functions, probably because it was only designed to support C-like languages. This affects VHDL as well as Ada. There are workarounds but they aren't pretty. If you can work at a much lower level than Ada, you may be able to use the gcc plugin interface to access the low level Gimple code, but I would agree with Simon that this is what ASIS is for.

Comment: I know somebody created a utility suite that included a logging utility that did enter/exit tracking, but damned if I can find it. It required instrumenting your source code with a variable declaration whose type was derived from Ada.Finalization.Controlled. The Initialize and Finalize methods were overridden to log the subprogram entry/exiting.